# Single volume for five Filestream databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, filestream

We are going ahead with PROD server setup. SQL Version 2014 AOAGs.

I have a question about the M:\ holding 5 Filestream databases totaling 1.5TB.

What will be the operational risks of running one single volume for all five databases?

I understand that this is the simplest form to deploy. However, in light of recent unforeseen Filestream volume issues...

Most likely, we will have 2.5TB of data in total in a couple of years.

From the SQL Server Technical Article [`FILESTREAM` Storage in SQL Server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh461480.aspx) by Paul S. Randal:

> #### Physical Storage Layout:
>
> Be sure to take into account the anticipated workload on a FILESTREAM data container when you are deciding where to place it, as well as the workloads on any co-located data containers or SQL Server files. Each FILESTREAM data container may need to be on its own volume, as having multiple data containers with heavy workloads on a single volume could lead to contention.
>
> The point to take away here is that without thinking about the workloads involved, simply placing everything on one volume may lead to performance problems. The degree of separation required will vary from customer to customer.
>
> It is also possible to create a table schema inside SQL Server that allows crude load balancing of FILESTREAM data between multiple volumes.